# How to specify Seat count in Uber ride request (SDK call)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, uber-api

We are implementing Uber functionality in our iOS app using pod. For requesting a ride we are using the SDK call(requestRideWithParameters) with build parameters(UBSDKRideParameters).

This ride parameter build with these parameters(in pod file):

```
 @objc public func builder() -> RideParametersBuilder {
        let builder = RideParametersBuilder()
        builder.productID = productID
        builder.pickupLocation = pickupLocation
        builder.pickupNickname = pickupNickname
        builder.pickupAddress = pickupAddress
        builder.pickupPlaceID = pickupPlaceID
        builder.dropoffLocation = dropoffLocation
        builder.dropoffNickname = dropoffNickname
        builder.dropoffAddress = dropoffAddress
        builder.dropoffPlaceID = dropoffPlaceID
        builder.paymentMethod = paymentMethod
        builder.surgeConfirmationID = surgeConfirmationID
        builder.source = source
        builder.upfrontFare = upfrontFare
        return builder
    }
```

There is no option for specifying seat count in this ride parameter object. 
In Uber developer site they mentioned for requesting Uber Pool like products we have to set the seat count otherwise it will take 2 as default. 
If we are using direct API call there is an option in request to specify seat count. But how can we implement the same with the Uber SDK call?

Comment: We're tracking this here: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/issues/224

Comment: @EdwardJiang. Ok we will wait for the next release. Now we are moving with default value(SDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS SDK for Uber does not give you one option to set seat count. It is only available to the https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk. So for your UberPOOL product, you will always have seat_count = 2 (default and MAX value). If you are using directly API's - you will have an option to specify seat_count for :

-POST /requests/estimate
-POST /requests

More info is available on the Uber [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/best-practices#uberpool).